# Is there a way to run sbt-native-packager within Gitlab shared runner?

Tags: docker, gitlab, sbt, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I've been trying to build docker images in Gitlab shared runner. I'm building my application using `image: "hseeberger/scala-sbt:11.0.6_1.3.10_2.11.12"` image normally and I locally build the docker image with sbt-native-packager which made me think that i need to use DiD service.

I'm currently having an issue which the sbt-native-packager cannot locate docker executable and fails to build the image. What I am missing here?

My script is as follows:

```
docker:
  stage: deploy
  image: "hseeberger/scala-sbt:11.0.6_1.3.10_2.11.12"
  services:
    - name: docker:dind
  script:
    - sbt docker:publishLocal
    - docker push registry.gitlab.com/groupName/moduleName
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following actually did the trick for me although it is quite heavy to install Docker in the runner every time, however, that's the only way I could make it work.

```
docker:image:
  stage: release
  image: "hseeberger/scala-sbt:11.0.6_1.3.10_2.11.12"
  before_script:
    - apt-get update
    - apt-get install sudo
    - apt-get install apt-transport-https ca-certificates curl software-properties-common -y
    - curl -fsSL https://download.docker.com/linux/debian/gpg | sudo apt-key add -
    - sudo add-apt-repository "deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/debian $(lsb_release -cs) stable"
    - apt-get update
    - apt-get install docker-ce -y
    - sudo service docker start
    - docker login <to your account>

  script:
    - sbt docker:publishLocal
    - docker tag module:latest registry.gitlab.com/moduleGroup/module:0.1-SNAPSHOT
    - docker push registry.gitlab.com/moduleGroup/module
```

Comment: I'm trying to figure this out right now - I think another approach is to do something along [these lines](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-foss/-/issues/20604), which might have the advantage of not including the docker login credentials in the repo. Also, I suppose you could start with dind, install sbt on top. and save that as a private image that the runner would build from.

Comment: Ah, I missed that the login credentials can be handled via $VARIABLES. This is working for me - I'm just using `docker:publish` rather than manually tagging and pushing. Thanks for posting!

Answer (score 0):

I've built and published docker images that contains sbt, docker and git; to simplify this common task. you can use it from [here](https://github.com/hnaderi/sbt-ci-image)
just use one of the built images, for example:
`hnaderi/sbt-ci-image:openjdk-11.0.16_1.8.0_3.2.0_20.10-cli`